# Error when creating scheduled event?

Tags: mysql-5.5, scheduled-tasks

I creating scheduled events in MySQL 5.5 (yes, I know, and we do have plans for upgrading, but we're kind of trapped here atm). I have done this before, like:

```
create event upd_ga_sum_1
on schedule every 1 day
  starts current_date + interval 1 day + interval 3 hour
  do call update_ga_sum_1();
```

But this one gives me an error:

```
mysql> create event fin_daily_sum_evt
    -> on schedule
    ->   every 1 day
    ->   starts current_date + interval 1 day + interval 1 hour
    -> comment 'Updates TABLE fin_daily_sum every day at 01:00'
    -> do
    ->   begin
    ->     call logmsg('fin_daily_sum_evt',concat('Daily update for ',now()));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
mysql>     call fin_daily_sum_upd(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day));

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (4.18 sec)
```

Is it not permitted to use compund statements (`begin` ... `end;`)? Or it is something obvious that my tired, old eyes just can't see?

This is the statement, for clarity:

```
drop event if exists fin_daily_sum_evt;
create event fin_daily_sum_evt
on schedule
  every 1 day
  starts current_date + interval 1 day + interval 1 hour
comment 'Updates TABLE fin_daily_sum every day at 01:00'
do
  begin
    call logmsg('fin_daily_sum_evt',concat('Daily update for ',now()));
    call fin_daily_sum_upd(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day));
  end;
```

Comment: You forget about DELIMITER reassign.

Comment: @Akina You're right, of course. Thanks!